# C++ template using pointer and non pointer arguments in a QVector

Tags: c++, qt, templates, pointers

I'm trying to avoid having to use "nearly" the same code twice. I have the following template function, which searches for the provided value in a `QVector` and returns the index to the element.

```
template<class tVec,class tVal>
int upperBoundIndex(const QVector<tVec> &vec,int first,int last,tVal value)
{
//code here
}
```

Searching for example a vector of the following type works fine: `QVector<int>`, however I'd like to also be able to search a vector of the type
`QVector<int*>`, so I wrote another template function.

```
template<class tVec,class tVal>
int upperBoundIndex(const QVector<tVec*> &vec,int first,int last,tVal value)
{
//similar code here, but the dereferencing
}
```

This also works fine, but I've been wondering, is there a way I can use the same code for both functions? Because I nearly copy and pasted the code from one function to the other, and so far whenever I changed something in one function I, jumped right to the other and applied the same changes, is there a more optimal solution?

p.s. I'm not looking for alternative search functions, I know there are search functions for example in the std namespace. I'd like to know if there's a way to optimize my approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could template your container Qvector and make it more generic with something like :

```
template<class Container>
int upperBoundIndex(const Container &vec,int first,int last,typename Container::value_type value)
{
 // your code
}
```

But I think you should use `std::upper_bound` where you even have an [example to get the index](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/).

So I would use this kind of reusable function instead :

```
template<class ForwardIt, class T>
T upperBoundIndex(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value)
{
    return (std::upper_bound (first, last, value) - first);
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/5E172T)

Comment: Thank you for your input, also I didn't consider using iterators. Another question, does the std::upper_bound(...) function use some kind of binary search, for an optimized performance? Because that's what I implemented in my function.

Comment: If you look the equivalent behavior code on  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/upper_bound/ you can remark it is indeed some binary search. The complexity is the same as std::binary_search if you scroll at the bottom. And generally, STL functions are rather preferred to use because they are optimized !